# Error: ‘int XYZ::data’ is private within this context

Tags: c++, oop, g++, private, friend-function

I have one question about the following code snippet in c++ :

```
 #include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

 class ABC;

 class XYZ
 {
 int data;
 public:

         void setvalue(int value)
         {
         data=value;
         } 
         friend void add(ABC,XYZ);
 };

 class ABC
 {
 int data;
 public:

         void setvalue(int value)
         {
         data=value;
         }
         friend void add(ABC,XYZ);
 };

 void add(XYZ obj1, ABC obj2)
 {
      cout << "Sum of data values of XYZ and ABC objects using friend function = " << obj1.data + obj2.data;
      cout << "\n";
 }


 int main()
 {

 XYZ X;
 ABC A;

 X.setvalue(5);
 A.setvalue(50);
 add(X,A);

 return 0;
 }
```

In particular, when I compile, g++ complains with the following log:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror friend_function_add_data.cpp -o friend_function_add_data.o
friend_function_add_data.cpp: In function ‘void add(XYZ, ABC)’:
friend_function_add_data.cpp:33:86: error: ‘int XYZ::data’ is private within this context
  33 | ut << "Sum of data values of XYZ and ABC objects using friend function = " << obj1.data + obj2.data;
     |                                                                                    ^~~~

friend_function_add_data.cpp:9:5: note: declared private here
   9 | int data;
     |     ^~~~
friend_function_add_data.cpp:33:98: error: ‘int ABC::data’ is private within this context
  33 |  data values of XYZ and ABC objects using friend function = " << obj1.data + obj2.data;
     |                                                                                   ^~~~

friend_function_add_data.cpp:21:5: note: declared private here
  21 | int data;
     |
```

Since it was complaining about `data` declared as `private`, I changed the declaration to public by placing `data` right after the `public` statement for each class `ABC` and `XYZ` .

In this way g++ compiles without problems.

What I wonder is : is this the only correct way to handle this issue for this example? do you think it is just a mistake by the author himself?

This piece of code is taken from Balagurusamy's "OOP programming with C++" (8th edition, page 124)

Edit: thanks Anoop for double checking! I realized I inverted the input arguments for each class ABC and XYZ, w.r.t. to the outer add function taking XYZ obj1 and ABC obj2. So it is written correctly on the book

Comment: The `add` function that you declare as friend takes arguments `ABC` and `XYZ`. Later, you define a function `add` that takes arguments `XYZ` and `ABC` (note the order!). These two are overloads, but are otherwise unrelated, and the second one is not a `friend` of anything. If this is really code from the book, the book has a mistake.

Comment: The sixth edition's version of the code (partially) can be found on Google Books. It has the parameters in the correct order (first `XYZ`, then `ABC`). Are you sure you didn't just make a mistake copying from the book? I would be surprised if the mistake was introduced in a later edition.

Comment: Thanks both Yksisarvinen and user17732522 for the reply. @Yksisarvinen: thank you for the explanation. @ user17732522 : yes, int data is placed before the public statement

Comment: @Stefano I mean, `int data` should be `private`. That's the point of `friend`, I assume the book should explain that. `friend` can access `private` members of a class. However, the important fact is that `void add(XYZ, ABC)` and `void add(ABC, XYZ)` are two different functions, and befriending one doesn't befriend the other.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen thanks for the clarification. I was wrong:  I double checked what I typed-in and I realized I actually  inverted the input arguments of ´´´ friend void add (XYZ,ABC)´´´ for both  classes ABC and XYZ w.r.t.  the void function taking first XYZ obj1 and then ABC obj2. And yes, the book states clearly that friend functions have full access over private members of each class. Sorry for the storm in a teacup and thanks again to both for spotting my mistake!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **problem** is that while defining the function `add`, the order of the two parameters named `obj1` and `obj2` is opposite to what it was in the **friend declaration**.

So to solve this, make sure that the order of the parameters match in the definition and the friend declaration as shown below:

```
class XYZ
{
public:
     //other code here
     friend void add(ABC,XYZ);
};
class ABC
{
public:

     //other code here
     friend void add(ABC,XYZ);
};
//ORDER OF PARAMETERS CHANGED TO MATCH WITH THE FRIEND DECLARATION
void add(ABC obj1, XYZ obj2)
{
  cout << "Sum of data values of XYZ and ABC objects using friend function = " << obj1.data + obj2.data;
  cout << "\n";
}
int main()
{

    XYZ X;
    ABC A;
    
    X.setvalue(5);
    A.setvalue(50);
    add(A,X); //ORDER OF ARGUMENTS CHANGED
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/YUV81ao1L)